# How to configure self hosted sentry with admin password?

Tags: sentry

I need to setup sentry with docker. Thats why I don't want to be asked for user creation during the installation process. Hence I used following command to install sentry.

```
./install.sh --no-user-prompt
```

In the config file config.example.yml I also set following values. Unfortunately I cant login.

```
system.secret-key: 'somesupersecretkey'
system.admin-email: 'somemail@adress.com'
```

How do I have to change the config file to have a user set up. And what ist the system.secrey-key for anyway?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no default username or password it prompts you to create a new user during installation.

If you skipped that step or used an unattended installation, you can run `docker-compose run --rm web createuser` to create one

[Default username & password](http://There%20is%20no%20default%20username%20or%20password,%20it%20prompts%20you%20to%20create%20a%20new%20user%20during%20installation.%20%20If%20you%20skipped%20that%20step%20or%20used%20an%20unattended%20installation,%20you%20can%20run%20docker-compose%20run%20--rm%20web%20createuser%20to%20create%20one)